# Simple Linear Regression problem involving its design matrix

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Problem states: Consider the simple linear regression model without intercept, i.e. $y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i, i = 1, 2, ..., n$

Write down your design matrix, $\mathbf X$.

So then  $\mathbf X$ $=$ $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\...\\x_n \end{bmatrix}$                                                                      $_{nx1}$

I believe this to be too simple, am I doing something wrong?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, for $n$ observations you can check that it results in the right model: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}
\beta
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_1\\
\epsilon_2\\
\vdots\\
\epsilon_n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so the $i$th row is 
$$
y_i = x_i\beta + \epsilon_i,
$$
as required.